# Search in MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I worked with mongo before 3 years and now I'm back in Mongo and I don't know why today search ('%LIKE%' in SQL) is not working.

What I tried is as below.

`{ "title": /${req.body.search}/i }`

I searched a lot I all most tried all the way but don't know it seems not bed of roses for me.

Note: If I put static text then it's working but I need dynamic as per user search in my app.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB exposes as `$regex` operator to allow you search for items.

You could handle it like this:

```
// in your search handler
const searchTerm = new RegExp(req.body.search, "i")
Model.find({ "title": { $regex: searchTerm } })
```